# Assign subprotocol as an associated type

Tags: swift, frameworks, protocols, associated-types

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do

```swift
protocol ThemeManager {
    associatedType ThemeClass: Theme
    var sharedTheme: ThemeClass { get }
}

protocol Theme {
   // ...
}

protocol AppTheme: Theme {
    var viewTheme: AppSpecificViewTheme { get set }
}

final class ThemeManager: Framework.ThemeManager {    
    var sharedTheme: AppTheme
}
```

The `ThemeManager` protocol lives in a external framework that I made to share between 2 apps, but now I want to add app-specific theme variables into the `Theme` protocol for all my Theme classes to add. `ThemeManager` class which lives in the app is failing to build if I use `AppTheme` protocol, but successfully build by passing in a concrete `Theme` class. Is there a way to make this work?

Edit:
I found this other question on SO that asks the same thing, with an explanation as to why this won't work. The explanation makes sense, but I'm still not sure why I can't define the protocol more since everything that conforms to `AppTheme` also conforms to `Theme`. My current workaround until I find a more permanent solution is just casting to `AppTheme` when needed.

Comment: Are both the `ThemeManager` and `Theme` in the framework?

Comment: `ThemeManager` protocol and `Theme` protocol are both in the framework. The classes that conform to `Theme` and `ThemeManager` class are in the apps. I want to share as much code between the 2 apps as I can. I suppose I could move ThemeManager into the framework if need be and have either a delegate or some other way or telling it where to load / safe themes from for each app.